# how to show data of list view's topper item on other widget in flutter

Tags: flutter

I have just created a demo for explaining what I want

I have a listview builder and a container that shows topper value of listview builder,
**here I don't mean to list view's 0 index value...**

when I scroll up or down, first container should be changed with  topper item of listview
[image]
here is my code

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Container(
              height: 200,
              color: Colors.red,
              child:
                  Center(child: Text('show data of topper of shown listview',style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),),
                  ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 10,
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.blue,
                child: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: mylist.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return Card(
                        child: ListTile(
                          title: Text(mylist[index]['name']),
                          subtitle: Text(mylist[index]['aboutme'],
                          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,),
                        ),
                      );
                    }),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First define this variable:

```
String topperValue = '';
GlobalKey itemKey = GlobalKey();
double itemHeight = 0.0;
ScrollController controller = ScrollController();
```

then in your `initState` do this:

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    controller.addListener(() {
      setState(() {
        var index = (controller.position.pixels / itemHeight).floor();
        topperValue = index < 1 ? '' : mylist[index - 1];
      });
    });
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      setState(() {
        final itemKeyContext = itemKey.currentContext;
        if (itemKeyContext != null) {
          final box = itemKeyContext.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
          itemHeight = box.size.height;
        }
      });
    });
  }
```

then use it like this:

```
  Container(
    height: 200,
    color: Colors.red,
    child: Center(
      child: Text(
        topperValue,
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
      ),
    ),
  ),
  SizedBox(
    height: 10,
  ),
  Expanded(
    child: Container(
      color: Colors.blue,
      child: ListView.builder(
          controller: controller,
          itemCount: mylist.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Card(
              key: index == 0 ? itemKey : null,
              child: ListTile(
                title: Text(mylist[index]),
                subtitle: Text(
                  mylist[index],
                  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                ),
              ),
            );
          }),
    ),
  )
```

[image]